# htaccess to replace url within source code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

is there a way to replace a url being called on all pages in the source code via htaccess? I'm unable to change the code on the pages but have access to htaccess.

Example: each page calls a stylesheet form an external url. I want to change this via htacess to point to my own url elsewhere.

I tried this without success:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule
^http://3rdpartyurl.com/style.css$ http://differenturl.com/style.css [L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked for a different project successfully when the url being replaced both resided on my own domain but the urls called on all pages are for an external url.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a third party URL that isn't on your server, you won't be able to redirect it with any configuration on your server.

You could edit your code to change the URLs.

You could also use an Apache filter to modify the output to substitute the URLs before they are sent to the client.

xlate is the name of the filter, it will be applied to all HTML files and the command that will be executed is **sed s#oldURL#newURL#g**

```
ExtFilterDefine xlate mode=output cmd="/bin/sed s#oldURL#newURL#g"

<Directory /var/www/html/stuff>
AddOutputFilter xlate html
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that's really unfortunate but appreciate your help. I was hoping there would be some sort of search and replace function but sounds like it's not possible. Sounds like I'll need to find a way to edit each page (about a 100 pages are static html files...)